# Application Skeleton for YiiFramework

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am looking for a skeleton application for the YiiFramework to get me up-and-running with a simple PHP application I would like to build.  Some requirements are:

- A login/authentication system that keeps the current user's session state (and is secure from injection attacks, etc).
- It connects to a back-end database (MySql).
- Has an example table display that demonstrates CRUD operations.  i.e. List records from a specific table, a form to edit a specific record as well as pagination and basic search filter.
- A menu framework that can be easily added to.
- (Ideally) A pre-existing, visually appealing theme.
- (Ideally) Has a structure that supports language localisation.
- (Ideally) Has a framework for a REST API.

I have seen https://github.com/clevertech/yiibooster which provides a nice set of components that would take care of these requirements, however from what I understand, all the above would still need to be assembled.  I know that the YiiFramework is designed to make quick work of this, however I have never used any of these frameworks before and would learn *much* quicker from a pre-existing example/template (and/or existing Yii application) rather than going through the documentation.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: All of this is already implemented in Advanced Project Template for Yii 2

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I am looking into it now.  I have done numerous searches on Github & SourgeForge and there is a plethora of these sorts of frameworks available but given that few have demos/screenshots, I am finding myself taking 1+ hours to install the thing (I am still learning PHP) only to find that one of the above requirements is "missing" (i.e. I would need to go through the steep learning curve of learning the ins-and-outs of the framework before I could implement the functions I wanted).  Suggestions like yours will hopefully fast-track the process, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Bizley, Yii2 Advanced Project Template is a very good starting point to learn the concepts & get hands on with Yii2.

There are several other Yii2 templates available & most of them have been developed by customizing and/or adding features to the Yii2 Advanced Template. Just for your reference here are some Yii2 templates (in no particular order) -

**yii2-improved-advanced-template**

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-improved-advanced-template/

> **Introduction**
>
> Yii2-advanced-template is based on yii2-app-advanced created by yii2
>   core developers. There are several upgrades made to this template.
>
> This template has additional features listed in the next section.
>   Application structure has been changed to be 'shared hosting
>   friendly'.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Signup with/without account activation
> - Login using email/password or username/password combo.
> - Rbac tables are installed with other migrations when you run yii    migrate command.
> - Users with editor+ roles can create articles.
> - Session data is stored in database out of the box.
> - System setting are stored in config/params.php file ( changes from v2    ).
> - Theming is supported out of box.
> - Translation is supported out of the box.
> - Administrators and The Creator can manage users ( changes from v2 ).
> - Password strength validation and strength meter.
> - All functionalities of default advanced template are included in this    template.
> - Code is heavily commented out.

**Yii2 Practical App**

http://demos.krajee.com/app-practical

> **Why yii2-app-practical?**
>
> After installing a app in the yii2-advanced application you normally
>   would access the frontend from http://domain/app/frontend/web.
>
> However, in many practical scenarios (especially on single domain
>   hosts) one would want their users to directly access frontend
>   as:http://domain/app
>
> The yii2-app-practical enables you to achieve just that by carefully
>   moving and rearranging the bootstrap files and web components of
>   frontend to work directly out of the app root. The frontend/web is
>   entirely eliminated and one can directly access the application
>   frontend from http://domain/app
>
> All other aspects of the app configuration remain the same as the
>   yii2-advanced app. The common, backend and console will remain as is.
>   The frontend config, assets, models, controllers, views, widgets and
>   components, will still reside within the frontend directory. It is
>   just the web access that is moved out to app root.

**Yii 2 Starter Kit**

https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit

> This is Yii2 start application template.
>
> It was created and developing as a fast start for building an advanced
>   sites based on Yii2.
>
> It covers typical use cases for a new project and will help you not to
>   waste your time doing the same work in every project
>
> **FEATURES**
>
> - Beautiful and open source dashboard theme for backend AdminLTE 2
> - Translations: English, Spanish, Russian, Ukrainian, Chinese
> - Translations Editor
> - Language change action + behavior to choose locale based on browser    preferred language
> - Sign in, Sign up, profile(avatar, locale, personal data), email    activation etc
> - OAuth authorization
> - User management
> - RBAC with predefined guest, user, manager and administrator roles
> - RBAC migrations support
> - Content management components: articles, categories, static pages,    editable menu, editable carousels, text blocks
> - Key-value storage component
> - Application settings form (based on KeyStorage component)
> - Ready-to-go RESTful API module
> - File storage component + file upload widget
> - On-demand thumbnail creation trntv/yii2-glide
> - Command Bus with queued and async tasks support    trntv/yii2-command-bus
> - Useful behaviors (GlobalAccessBehavior, CacheInvalidateBehavior,    MaintenanceBehavior)
> - Yii2 log web interface
> - Application timeline component
> - Cache web controller
> - Maintenance mode component (more)
> - System information web interface
> - dotenv support
> - ExtendedMessageController with ability to replace source code    language and migrate messages between message sources
> - Aceeditor widget
> - Datetimepicker widget,
> - Imperavi Reactor Widget,
> - Elfinder Extension
> - Xhprof Debug panel
> - Extended IDE autocompletion
> - Nginx config example
> - Test-ready
> - Docker support and Vagrant support
> - Built-in mailcatcher
> - Assets compression and concatenation
> - Some useful shortcuts
> - many other features i'm lazy to write about :-)

I guess these should be more than enough to get you started.

Comment: Good answer, in addition you should have a look at Gii, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html, it will take care of all your CRUD needs, and is included in Yii2.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, @sm1979!  The "yii-starter-kit" seems the way to go.  I am having some issues installing though so I raised another question here if you or others know the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40869560/installing-yii2-starter-kit-under-localhost.  (P. S. I voted for your answer but my privileges are low).

Comment: @SimpleGuy seems like you were able to sort out issue with Yii2 Starter Kit installation. Thanks for the upvote. Enjoy Yii2!